# Rendering chart.js using phantomjs results in ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, phantomjs, server-side

I am trying to render a chart.js chart using phantomjs. However, upon running phantomjs, I get error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Chart`. Opening the HTML file, that I am trying to render, in a browser works without this problem.

- PhantomJS's script file:

```js
page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('file:///path/to/file.html', function()
{
    page.viewportSize = {
        width: 850,
        height: 300
    };

    page.render('graph.png');

    phantom.exit(0);
});
```

- `file.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The command that I use to run PhantomJS: `phantomjs.exe script.js`. I am using PhantomJS version `2.1.1`.

Is there something that I forgot to set or configure?

Comment: Probably the cause of your problem is the fact that you get the html through the `file` protocol. I'd try: 1) saving and linking to the `chart.js` file locally, or even better 2) getting `file.html` through a (local) webserver

Comment: Tried linking the chart.js locally and getting the file.html via webserver but both resulted in the same error.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong; by testing various combinations I got to the conclusion that `phantom.js`'s obsolete javascript engine fails to parse the source file  of `chart.js`, which  is compiled to at least es6. A simple test shows that, for instance, `phantomjs` fails if there's a basic script that contains a template string. The last version of `chart.js` that seems to be accepted by `phantomjs` is 2.9.4